# Compare altcoins in one chart

Tags: altcoin, exchange-rate, charts

Is there a website where I can compare several altcoins in one chart?

In particular, I am looking for a chart where each coin, that I want to consider, starts with the same value (say a value of 100$) at a certain date. With such a chart one could compare the performance of the altcoins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this website](https://www.cryptocurrencychart.com/chart/BTC,ETH,XRP,BCH2,ETC/valueUsd/linear/2017-02-07/2018-02-02), They may be what you're looking for.